# traefik can't find front & backends

Tags: traefik

I run traefik by this command (with docker):

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v ~/playground/docker/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock traefik:1.7.4-alpine
```

and put this configuration on traefik.toml:

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"

[file]
    watch = true

[backends]
    [backends.backend1]
        [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
        url = "http://172.17.0.1:5000"
        weight = 0

[frontends]
    [frontends.frontend1]
        backend = "backend1"
            [frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
            rule = "Host:linker.test"

[api]

[ping]

[docker]
```

When I check traefik dashboard, there isn't **frontend1** & **backend1**! I make this configuration from traefik's doc and I can't figour out what happened!

Why it can't detect my **frontend1** & **backend1**? What did I wrong?

This is container log:

```
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=info msg="I have to go..."
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=info msg="Stopping server gracefully"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 10s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint traefik..."
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 10s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint http..."
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint traefik closed"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint http closed"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=info msg="Server stopped"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:50Z" level=info msg="Shutting down"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.7.4 built on 2018-10-30_10:44:30AM"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {\"LifeCycle\":{\"RequestAcceptGraceTimeout\":0,\"GraceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"GraceTimeOut\":0,\"Debug\":true,\"CheckNewVersion\":true,\"SendAnonymousUsage\":false,\"AccessLogsFile\":\"\",\"AccessLog\":null,\"TraefikLogsFile\":\"\",\"TraefikLog\":null,\"Tracing\":null,\"LogLevel\":\"DEBUG\",\"EntryPoints\":{\"http\":{\"Address\":\":80\",\"TLS\":null,\"Redirect\":null,\"Auth\":null,\"WhitelistSourceRange\":null,\"WhiteList\":null,\"Compress\":false,\"ProxyProtocol\":null,\"ForwardedHeaders\":{\"Insecure\":true,\"TrustedIPs\":null}},\"traefik\":{\"Address\":\":8080\",\"TLS\":null,\"Redirect\":null,\"Auth\":null,\"WhitelistSourceRange\":null,\"WhiteList\":null,\"Compress\":false,\"ProxyProtocol\":null,\"ForwardedHeaders\":{\"Insecure\":true,\"TrustedIPs\":null}}},\"Cluster\":null,\"Constraints\":[],\"ACME\":null,\"DefaultEntryPoints\":[\"http\"],\"ProvidersThrottleDuration\":2000000000,\"MaxIdleConnsPerHost\":200,\"IdleTimeout\":0,\"InsecureSkipVerify\":false,\"RootCAs\":null,\"Retry\":null,\"HealthCheck\":{\"Interval\":30000000000},\"RespondingTimeouts\":null,\"ForwardingTimeouts\":null,\"AllowMinWeightZero\":false,\"KeepTrailingSlash\":false,\"Web\":null,\"Docker\":{\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":true,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false,\"Network\":\"\"},\"File\":{\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":0,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Directory\":\"\",\"TraefikFile\":\"/etc/traefik/traefik.toml\"},\"Marathon\":null,\"Consul\":null,\"ConsulCatalog\":null,\"Etcd\":null,\"Zookeeper\":null,\"Boltdb\":null,\"Kubernetes\":null,\"Mesos\":null,\"Eureka\":null,\"ECS\":null,\"Rancher\":null,\"DynamoDB\":null,\"ServiceFabric\":null,\"Rest\":null,\"API\":{\"EntryPoint\":\"traefik\",\"Dashboard\":true,\"Debug\":true,\"CurrentConfigurations\":null,\"Statistics\":null},\"Metrics\":null,\"Ping\":{\"EntryPoint\":\"traefik\"},\"HostResolver\":null}"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#collected-data\n"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc0003cbd40} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Preparing server traefik &{Address::8080 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc0003cbd60} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Starting provider configuration.ProviderAggregator {}"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :8080"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":true,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false,\"Network\":\"\"}"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *file.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":0,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Directory\":\"\",\"TraefikFile\":\"/etc/traefik/traefik.toml\"}"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider file: {\"backends\":{\"backend1\":{\"servers\":{\"server1\":{\"url\":\"http://172.17.0.1:5000\",\"weight\":0}},\"circuitBreaker\":{\"expression\":\"NetworkErrorRatio() \\u003e 0.5\"}}}}"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :8080"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 18.09.0 (API 1.39)"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[org.label-schema.version:v1.7.4 org.label-schema.description:A modern reverse-proxy org.label-schema.docker.schema-version:1.0 org.label-schema.name:Traefik org.label-schema.url:https://traefik.io org.label-schema.vendor:Containous]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[]]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container with empty frontend rule /kind_leavitt "
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[com.sonatype.license:Apache License, Version 2.0 com.sonatype.name:Nexus Repository Manager base image org.label-schema.schema-version:= 1.0     org.label-schema.name=CentOS Base Image     org.label-schema.vendor=CentOS     org.label-schema.license=GPLv2     org.label-schema.build-date=20180531 vendor:Sonatype]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[]]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container with empty frontend rule /nexus "
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[]]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container with empty frontend rule /personal-postgres "
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="originLabelsmap[]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="allLabelsmap[:map[]]"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container with empty frontend rule /portainer "
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {}"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
time="2018-11-08T12:22:51Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :8080"
```

---

The solution is on chats by @Marvin

- try to remove both [ping] and [docker] : for testing purpose since
  you don't need them atm
- remove the 'watch = true ' from within the
  [file] node, since this one will be watching for an expected existing
  file, which does not
- Check your docker version, and update if needed
- Remove 'weight = 0' since there's only one backend and furthermore I
  am not sure '0' is a valid value

when I remove [ping] and [docker] it's work fine!

Comment: Did you see anything odd in traefik's logs?... docker logs <you traefik container id>

Comment: I can't find log out put! Where is default log out put?

Comment: Normally they are sent to stdout. Thus, performing a 'docker logs' on your container should show them. you can also try configuring the logs so that it writes in a file, but the file would be inside the container, unless you target a volume that is mounted over an existing one on the host

Comment: OK, I add log file to my question; Can it help?

Comment: nothing odd.... Do you run your backend on a container as well? Are you in SWARM mode? In case your backend is also a contaier, did you try to do the same configuration using labels instead? https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers

Comment: No, my my backend is a flask app that run on my machine, I wanna test traefik before dockerize my app. Can I do this without make docker container for my app? (My app doesn't complete yet)

Comment: What about front, because in traefik dashboard, I can't see any front or backend.

Comment: If you look at your network (eg using browser dev tools), do you see the providers requests returning (empty) with code 200 or... ?

Comment: Yes, I can see. From my machine and traefik's container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183350/discussion-between-marvin-and-glinboy).